# jQuery removes textarea placeholder when clearing textarea text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal with a textarea in it.  When you open the modal, the textarea needs to be cleared of any previous text so it's fresh every time you open it.

The problem is, the placeholder on the field is also removed the first time you clear the text.

I am using `$('textarea').val('')` to clear the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/dkRS8/1/

Comment: Works just fine for me in Chrome ?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Seems like it is fine for the first time.. but later after closing it once.. the placeholder text is gone.. Not sure if that is what he meant.. (pressed ESC to close that dialog)

Comment: Nope - still fine in Chrome, either clicking off or using Esc to close the dialog.  The placeholder is visible every time I open it.

Comment: This works fine for me as well.

Comment: His bug appears when you open the modal, start typing something and then close it. Next time you open the modal, the textarea is properly emptied from previou value but the placeholder was not here.

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the `blur` event for the placeholder to appear again. And it works only during the hide event, so that when it appears again the placeholder is put back.

```
$('#modal').on('hide', function() {
    $(this).find('textarea').val('').blur();
});
```

working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkRS8/5/)

**EDIT**: I was wrong, it seems that it works without the blur by just changing the event from `show` to `hide` as explained by Martin in his answer where he uses the event `shown`

Answer (score 2):

It does work when you register to the "shown" event instead of the "show" event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#modal').on('shown', function() {
        $(this).find('textarea').val('');
    });

});
```

Comment: the [bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) says to "shown" event: "This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for css transitions to complete)."

Comment: don't know about IE 9, seems to ignore placeholder completely :(

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modal').bind('hide',function(){
        $('textarea',this).val('')
    })
});
```

multi-browser, jquery-ui event standar

Answer (score -1):

**Among the IE versions.. IE 10 only support place holder**.... So dont try this thig on older versions of IE....

but other browsers like firefox, Chrome, Opera ... all support this attribute...

try the below code it will help you...

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dkRS8/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#modal').on('show', function() {
        var ele = $(this).find('textarea');
        ele.val('');
    });

});
```

Comment: You removed its placeholder, that's not what he wanted

Comment: @koopajah : Oh ok i think he asked to remove the placeholder... because his code works fine for me... so only i think wrongly...